# Go to XY tool in an ArcGIS online web map and/or application

Tags: arcgis-online

Has anybody created any language to attach to an ArcGIS online web map and/or application for a "Go to XY" tool?

Answer (score 1):

There is an ArcGIS Idea requesting this called [Add GOTO XY widget in Web Appbuilder](https://community.esri.com/ideas/11226):

> Please add a widget to ArcGIS Online Web Appbuilder to enable a user
>   to enter an XY coordinate and then GO TO that coordinate or make it
>   flash or label it, like in the ArcGIS Desktop software.

I recommend that you vote for it, if you have not already.